# How to solve Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in Drupal installation on line 171?

Tags: drupal

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded on line 171

I am new in the world of drupal My port no.80 is assigned to my ASP server so I changed my Apache server from 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf , BTW I am using XAMPP server I got Error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyDemoWebsite\core\modules\mysql\src\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection.php on line 171" while install site after Set up database in core instal [Set up database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8ke.png)

[Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CIEI.png)

May be I am doing somthing wrong in Set Up Database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfEos.png)   I have tried by changing the port no. to 8080[port no. to 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFOvO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're doing it first time. So, you have confused Apache port with mysql port.

[image: xampp-mysql-apache-ports]

You can see, I have started Xampp, here I am running Apache, with http and https, in ports (80, and 443) now according to the availability of ports in your pc, you can change them

Now, comes the **database** i.e. MySQL, whose port is normally 3306, or you can change to something else, according to your availability.

During Drupal installation. The database port which you have put as `8080`, will be `3306`, if you have not changed it either, which you can check from your xampp control panel, as I have added screenshot.

Now, as apache is running on port `8080`, then your site will run on `localhost:8080/<folder-name>`, by default apache port is `80` which is omitted by browser, if that changed to anything else, which requires to be mentioned on `http` address